# How to get parent function This inside child function using async.each

Tags: javascript, async.js

```
var self= this; //parent function context/this

async.each(smpleArray, sampleFunc, function(err){
// if any of the saves produced an error, err would equal that error
});
```

This is sample function :

```
var sampleFunc= function(){
var self = this; //window object

//do something
}
```

I want to fetch the parent's this context inside child.
But i am getting windows object there.

I tried:

```
async.each(smpleArray, sampleFunc, function(err){
// if any of the saves produced an error, err would equal that error
}.bind(this));
```

But its not working.

How to get the parent's self/this inside child function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind the context to the correct function, i.e. sampleFunc like this:

```
sampleFunc.bind(this)
```

So your example would be:

```
var sampleFunc = function () {
    // this is set to parent function context/this
    // do something
};

async.each(sampleArray, sampleFunc.bind(this), function (err) {
    // if any of the saves produced an error, err would equal that error
});
```